# Reconnect network drive on git push

Tags: windows, git, network-drive

I have a github repository with an origin that sits on a shared network drive. They are often disconnected when idle or after rebooting my Laptop. They do get automatically reconnected when I open them in the windwos explorer.

However, when I perform `git push` or similar commands, they don't, causing the command to fail as it cannot reach `origin`. Is there an easy way to set up a git action that will reconnect the relevant network drive (Y in this case) prior to the push?

Comment: Call `net use` in [`pre-push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_push) hook? For non-push subcommands there're no hooks so the only way I can imagine is to write a `git` wrapper that checks if the subcommand needs network access and calls `net use`.